# Passing a variable from one method to another method?

Tags: java

Assuming I am working on creating a deck of cards game, I have two methods called shuffle and randomInt in my class.

```
private static void shuffle(Card [] cardArray) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; s++) {
        Card temp = cardArray[a];
        cardArray[a] = cardArray[b];
        cardArray[b] = temp;
    }
}

private static void randomInt(int a, int b) {   
    a = (int)(Math.random() * 12);
    b = (int)(Math.random() * 12);
}
```

Question here is how can I pass the variable `a` and `b` from method `randomInt()` into the `shuffle()` method? I understand that I can simply put in this `randomInt()` inside `shuffle()` and it will work fine, but I will like to know if there is any way to do it this way.

Will appreciate for someone to explain on the concept too as I am fairly new to OOP. Thank you.

Comment: Your `swap` method doesn't actually swap anything, it just assigns values to two variables that are local to the method

Comment: If you want to pass something to a method you usually include it as a parameter, what's the problem with doing that here?

Comment: Edited my post by renaming the swap. I am trying to figure out what is the correct input for cardArray[?] as putting in cardArray[a] will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your `randomInt()` return the number and call the function inside of `shuffle()`.

```
private static void shuffle(Card[] cardArray) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        int a = randomInt();
        int b = randomInt();
        Card temp = cardArray[a];
        cardArray[a] = cardArray[b];
        cardArray[b] = temp;
    }
}

private static int randomInt() {   
    return (int)(Math.random() * 12);
}
```

This will shuffle your card deck according to the way `randomInt()` generates the indices

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there no way to do the variable pass with my given code above?

Comment: since you override `a` and `b` there is no reason to pass them into the function

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this as the answer since this method works well and did not deviate too far from my original code.

Answer (score 0):

u can create a Deck class and put ur logic and data in this class

```
public class Deck {
    private Card[] deck = new Card[52];
    public Deck(){
        initDeck();
    }
    public void shuffle() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            int a = (int)(Math.random() * 12);
            int b = (int)(Math.random() * (52 - 12));
            swap(a,b);
        }
    }
    private void swap(int a,int b){
        Card temp = deck[a];
        deck[a] = deck[b];
        deck[b] = temp;
    }
    private void print() {
       ...
    }

}
```

and in ur main method doing somthing like that

```
Deck d = new Deck();
deck.shuffle();
deck.print();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I have this class and the methods are all in a similar class like this. I am trying to know how to pass the variable a and b from swap to shuffle so I can do the shuffling of deck.

Comment: ur method is static and i think u have to share Card[] data between methods. u have to model ur world correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to return two values a and b from your method randomInt, you cannot just declare a and b as parameters. Method parameters in java are "ByValue" parameters. The method does not change the value on the caller's a and b values.

**Preferred option:**

let randomInt return an array with two elements. After invocation of randomInt you can assign the values from the array to your variables a and b in the caller method.

**Alternative option, pseudo by-references via an array:**

instead of passing a and b, pass an array with just one element to your method:

```
private static void randomInt(int[] a, int[] b)
{ 
  //assuming a[] and b[] both are an array with just one element
  //set a[0] and b[0] here like you already set a and b
}
```

and on the caller side,

```
...
int[] a = new int[1];
int[] b = new int[1];
randomInt(a, b);

//now you have your values in a[0] and b[0].
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, the method doesn't work as you supposed to (https://www.google.com/?q=java+call+by+value ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/592355), but you can work around:

- You can encapsulate your output variables inside an object (which modification will persist after the method exits):

  with

  ```
  class TwoInts {
     int a,b;
  }
  ```

  and:

  ```
  private static void randomInt(TwoInts container) {
    assert(conatiner != null);   
    container.a = (Math.random() * 12);
    container.b = (Math.random() * 12);
  }
  ```
- The straight forward approach would be to (write a method with one return value):

  ```
   private static int rand(int offset, int max) {
      return (int) (Math.random() * max) + offset;
   }
  ```

  ..and to invoke it twice:

  ```
   a = rand(0, 12);
   b = rand(0, 12);
  ```
- ...

Please also have a look at `java.util.Random`...

Answer (score -3):

You can declare the a and b variable global

```
int a,b;

private static void shuffle(Card [] cardArray)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; s++)
    { 
       randomint();
       Card temp = cardArray[a];
       cardArray[a] = a;
       cardArray[b] = b;
    }
}

private static void randomInt()
{   
    a = (Math.random() * 12);
    b = (Math.random() * 12);
}
```

Comment: No, you can't - you could make them `static` members of the class. Also why would you then have input parameters on `randomInt`?

Comment: Indeed, currently as you've got them as method parameters as well, the meaning of `a` in the `randomInt` method is the parameter, not the variable. (And the call to `randomint` would fail as it doesn't provide any arguments - and there's a capitalization issue.)